# failed to push origin master in special repository

Tags: git

In Git Bash command:

[image]

In TortoiseGit GUI:

[image]

In SourceTree GUI:

[image]

But push to other branch is OK, only master is not OK. And other repositories in my namespace are all normal, including master branch.

Comment: Are there any commits on origin/master that you haven't pulled?

Comment: Many git repositories don't allow pushing to master and only follow the PR process (where pull requests are merged onto master, but no one can directly push to master).

Comment: 1、I have pulled all of commits

Comment: 2、fork to my private  namespace, push to master of my private namespace then create PR to merge into common namespace